# Save the date of the day in a label

Tags: swift, save, label

I'm getting problem saving the date and the time of the day in a label. I have a TodoList that when I add something show the date and the time of when you did it. What I want to do is save it. For save I tried with user default but I have always the date and the time of the day and not of when I did. I think I'm doing something wrong. Any suggest of how can I save the date?

```
@IBOutlet weak var Data: UILabel!

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    Data.text = String(describing: DateFormatter())

    let dataFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dataFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy H:mm a"
    Data.text = dataFormatter.string(from: .init())

    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(Data.text!, forKey: "Data")
    Data!.text=UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Data")
}
```

Comment: FYI - The line `Data.text = String(describing: DateFormatter())` makes no sense at all. Please delete that line. Never use `setValue(_:,forKey:)` with `UserDefaults`. Use the proper `set(:_,forKey:)` method as shown in the `UserDefaults` documentation. Never hardcode a date format like "dd/MM/yy". It will make no sense to most users in the world. Use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` so the date and time are properly localized. Note that none of these suggestions address your immediate issue of always showing "now" in the text field.

Comment: `H` is used 24h time for (0-23 hours) and you wouldn't want it combined with am/pm symbol. you should use `h` for 12h time which means (1-12 hours)

Answer (score 0):

Okay from what I understand you have a list of to do items and you're trying to save the time each item was edited at.

**UserDefaults** is a key value pair and from what I see that you're trying to use the same key for possibly all your cells which will mean they'll override each other.

Also you're trying to write over the value existing every time before you use it is that the correct behavior you desire?

Comment: Exactly I have a todo list and I’m trying to add the date of the day every time you add or edit something

Comment: You're going to need a unique key for each cell's information if you're gonna do it this way.

Or

You can take a look at Core data as it is much better suited for this type of app since you can just make a struct of the type you like and it can carry the information you want like content of the to-do, is it done or not and it's date

Answer (score 0):

I will first cover some app development basics in the first part, then answer your question in the second part and lastly motivate why I introduced the app dev basics from the first part.

## Domain model

Usually when you make an app, you define your model first.

> A model object groups the data you need for a specific problem domain
>   or a type of solution you're trying to build. They are made up of properties that represent attributes of the type, and they sometimes have methods for updating and modifying their own properties.
>
> In most cases, you'll create a model object by defining a new structure or class. And you'll typically define the structure or class in a new Swift file.

This is an excerpt from Unit 4.3 Model View Controller of [App Development with Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/be/book/app-development-with-swift/) - Apple Education. A very interesting book if you are new to application development.

A model of a todo item in your application might look like:

```
struct TodoItem: Codable {
  let content: String
  let creationDate: Date
  init(with string: String) {
    content = string
    creationDate = Date()
  }
}
```

## Saving todo items with creation dates

Now to answer your question on how to save different questions with their corresponding creation date, it is a good practice to store these things also in your model. For example you could create a new array to store all the different `TodoItem`s (reusing `TodoItem` from my previous example) like this:

```
var todoList = [TodoItem]()
```

When the user creates a new item: add a `TodoItem` to the `todoList` using

```
todoLists.append(TodoItem(with: someUserContent))
```

## Motivation

- By defining your ‘model’ as a `TodoItem` struct and a `todoList` you can now be sure that whenever you access your list of items, the corresponding creationDate will be the exact date of the creation of the item. This is because we declared the `creationDate` as a constant.
- By conforming the `TodoItem` struct to `Codable` You can now use libraries like [Nirma/Default](https://github.com/Nirma/Default) to easily save and retrieve your `todoList` to and from user defaults.
- Since you now have an array containing all your todoItems it is very easy to display these dates in your label using:

.

```
dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: todoList[itemIndex].creationDate)
```